# What proportion of the Austro-Hungarian army fought on each of the fronts?

Tags: world-war-one, austria-hungary

During WWI, Austria-Hungary fielded an army of approximately 7.8 million soldiers.  They fought against Russia in the east, Italy in the west, and Serbia (mainly) in the south.

**What proportion of the Austro-Hungarian army fought on each of these fronts?**

I've been searching for some rough numbers for a while, and I haven't been able to come up with anything.  There's plenty of information readily available about the western front, and very little about any other fronts of the war.

Comment: If I may add, I'd also be interested in which proportion of the army was doing support work and not be fighting on a front (presumably the majority). And also if one soldier's ethnicity was taken in account to decide where to send him (for example, a southern slav would be more motivated to fight Italia than Russia, but an Italian the other way around)

Comment: Russian Wiki ( https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki//Вооружённые_силы_Австро-Венгрии ) (I don't know why the link comes corrupted) gives a year-by-year breakdown. It only quote the Russian references though. If needed I can translate the appropriate section.

Comment: @user58697, that's pretty much exactly what I'm looking for.  If you (or anyone else) posts it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Joe With pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Russian Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8) gives the following breakdown:

According to an Austrian military archive, upon mobilization in August 14, the Austrian forces consisted of 68.4 divisions. Of them 53.5 divisions (78.1%) headed to the Russian front, 15 divisions (21.9%) to the Serbian. In February 1915 there was 63.5 divisions, of which 51 (80.35) fought against Russians, 8.5 (13.4%) agains Serbians, and 4 divisions (6.3%) stayed at the Italian border.

Upon Italy entering the war, Austria concentrated against it 21 divisions (30.7%), while on Russian front there remained 39.5 (57.7%). On Serbian front there was 8 divisions (11.6%). By February 1916 the contigent dropped sharply at Balkans to 4.9%, and somewhat rose at Russian and Italian fronts (59.2% and 35.9% correspondingly). Half a year later at Russsian front there were 45 divisions (58.6%), and 29.75 (38.9%) at Italian. At Balcans there were just 2 divisions (2.6%).

By February 1917 Austria had 82.25 divisions, of which 59.6% were at the Russian front. ... During the Russian's summer offense of 1917 there were 53.8 Austrian divisions (60.3%). At that time at the Italian front there were 32.75 divisions (36.9%), at Balkans - 2.5 divisions (2.8%). At the truce of Brest there was 43.5 divisions against Russia and 41.25 at Italian front.

15.25 Austrian divisions participated in occupation of Russian territories, while the bulk of the forces (73.8%) were at Italy. 2 divisions remained at Balkans, and 2 more were sent to France.

Comment: Any idea which sources the Russian Wikipedia used to support these numbers?

Comment: @user69715 They refer to Austrian military archive, but no document is identified.